# Loading fact table with dimension key that are not in stream

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I want to load fact table and one of my dimension is not in the stream and I want to store that dimension key to my fact table when my transformation runs.
Issue is that dimension key is not present in my stream then how can I compare my key to stream

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: I have a lookup table that store data for my user type and I want to match with that as my lookup is not in my stream and I want to store the foreign key of a lookup table in my fact.

Comment: And why don't you put the desired values in the stream, too? PDI can't just guess values, you need to tell it where to take the data from.